# WearableListView ClassNotFoundException Support v4 ArrayMap

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, wear-os

Ok this is a fun one: I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0, I have an Android app and a correlating Android Wear app i'm trying to test on a smart watch device. I've placed the class files I used in my Android app into an Android library module then added it as a dependency into my Android Wear app. The app builds and deploys onto the smart watch but when it runs I get the below exception and stack trace. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
04-17 21:55:45.764    7759-7759/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.wear, PID: 7759
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:179)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onApplyWindowInsets(WatchViewStub.java:148)
            at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:6514)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1205)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1423)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:179)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onApplyWindowInsets(WatchViewStub.java:148)
            at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:6514)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1205)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1423)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State.<init>(RecyclerView.java:7461)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:233)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView.<init>(WearableListView.java:151)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView.<init>(WearableListView.java:147)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:179)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onApplyWindowInsets(WatchViewStub.java:148)
            at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:6514)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1205)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1423)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.wear-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.wear-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State.<init>(RecyclerView.java:7461)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:233)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView.<init>(WearableListView.java:151)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView.<init>(WearableListView.java:147)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:179)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onApplyWindowInsets(WatchViewStub.java:148)
            at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:6514)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1205)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1423)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 36 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Here's a visual of the gradle configs and modules: 
[image: library config]
[image: wear config]

Comment: What do you mean by 'placed the class files used in my Android app' - is there a reason you aren't just adding the wearable support library as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I couldn't use the namespace and subsequent classes from my main app in my wearable app since it was a separate module and that module wasn't a library. So I copied them into a library to be able to use them in the wear app. Are you saying the wear app shouldn't be setup as a separate module in Android Studio? Thanks!

Comment: I added a couple screenshots to add clarity in case i'm not explaining it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap` in your  logcat trace. And I think maybe the version of your `v4` and `v7` cause this error. Is your support library of `v4` and `v7` is up to date? And BTW, `ArrayMap` only could be used for `Android API 21+`

Comment: Good catch. Rookie mistake on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case , I solved this issue by deleting the **android-support-v4.jar** because it's old and has not actually **ArrayMap.class** and I put the one from  **\extras\android\support\v4** in my lib folder
and then add it to Java build path and it worked finally.
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

My case was after upgrading

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

to

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Going back to 8.1.0 solved it for me

Comment: This is not a good solution. Instead of downgrading the Google Play Services library, you should upgrade the support library to a version that includes `ArrayMap`.

Comment: My answer is specific about what worked for me, never mentioned it was the most optimal. Besides, since I didn't need the lastest functions, downgrading had no impact at all

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution to this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726985/4034572).

The error is very clear (basically `ArrayMap` is missing):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
```

This happens because **the support library version is old**, and another library (presumably Google Play Services) doesn't find `ArrayMap` on it.

The solution is to **upgrade the support library** to a new version that includes `ArrayMap`. That's what I did and it worked.

In addition, according the [linked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726985/4034572) you should also:

> make sure that your `compileSdkVersion` matches the major version number of
>   the dependency